# Finding $F' \le \Bbb R^4$ such that $F' \oplus F = \Bbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, systems-of-equations

In an exercise I'm asked the following:

> Let $F$ be a subspace of $\Bbb R ^4$ represented, in relation to certain base, by the system of equations:
> $$\begin{cases}
> x_1 + x_2  = 0 \\
> x_1 - x_3 = 0
> \end{cases}$$
> Determine a system of equations that represent $F'$ such that $F' \leq \Bbb R^4$ and $\Bbb R^4 = F'\oplus F$

In this exercise, the teacher introduced the variables $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ without saying what they were. I suppose that those are the coordinates $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in relation to the basis they refer, and then $F$ would be the set of the points whose coordinates satisfy the equation. But I'm not sure.

I am asking, to someone who is familiar with the concepts used here, if you can figure out by the context what those variables are. If possible I would also want some help/tips for solving this exercise. Thank you.

Comment: Your interpretation of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ and $F$ is 100% correct

Comment: Then, how can I solve this? @diracdeltafunk

Comment: Well, first, what is the dimension of $F$? This will be helpful because we must have $\dim(F) + \dim(F') = 4$, so we will at least know what the dimension of $F'$ is supposed to be.

Comment: I assume that $\text{dim}(F) = 3$ because the vectors of $F$ only have 3 coordinates $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$, and this would mean that the basis for $F$ only has 3 elements   @diracdeltafunk

Comment: This is a misunderstanding, I think. $F$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$, so every element of $F$ is a $4$-tuple of real numbers. Only 3 variables appeared in the equations defining $F$, but that's unrelated. For example (working in the standard basis), we have $(1,-1,1,0) \in F$. But this does not mean that $F$ is $4$-dimensional! For example, the $x$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a $1$-dimensional space whose elements are pairs of real numbers.

Comment: Then, how can I find the dimension of $F$? @diracdeltafunk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116901/discussion-between-diracdeltafunk-and-eduardo-magalhaes).